# When a creature is exiled with Nightmare Shepherd, does Teysa Karlov create two copies of the creature when dying?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

### Example

I have [Teysa Karlov](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeysa%20Karlov%5d) and [Nightmare Shepherd](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNightmare%20Shepherd%5d) in play. They mention, respectively:

> If a creature dying causes a triggered ability of a permanent you control to trigger, that ability triggers an additional time.

> Whenever another nontoken creature you control dies, you may exile it. If you do, create a token that’s a copy of that creature, except it’s 1/1 and it’s a Nightmare in addition to its other types.

Then, I sacrifice my [Doomed Dissenter](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoomed%20Dissenter%5d):

> When Doomed Dissenter dies, create a 2/2 black Zombie creature token.

### Confusion

I'm still not sure about replacement effects and whether or not the Doomed Dissenter in this case actually dies, when I choose to let it go into exile to copy it as a token. Because the demon's ability doesn't mention "instead", I think the human still "hits" the graveyard before going into exile. This would mean Teysa *does* trigger twice, creating two 2/2 Zombies. **Does the Nightmare Shepherd also create two copies of the Doomed Dissenter?**

This case confuses me, since I can only exile the creature once? But the death trigger still happens twice instead of once? Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**You get two 2/2 zombie tokens and up to one 1/1 Doomed Dissenter token.**

Both Doomed Dissenter's ability and Nightmare Shepherd's ability trigger twice on Doomed Dissenter's death (i.e. it moved from the battlefield to the graveyard).

> 700.4. The term dies means “is put into a graveyard from the battlefield.”

These abilities are now on the stack. Dissenter's own ability will resolve, no matter what happens to the Doomed Dissenter card in the graveyard, and you will eventually get 2 zombie tokens.

When it comes to resolving Nightmare Shepherd's ability, assuming you choose to exile the Dissenter card with the first instance, you get a 1/1 Dissenter token. The second Shepherd ability will no longer have a Dissenter card to exile, so that instance does nothing. If you don't choose to exile the Dissenter with the first ability, you can still do so with the second.

There are no replacement effects involved with these cards. None of the abilities have the words "instead" or any other term required for identifying as a replacement effect.

> 614.1a Effects that use the word “instead” are replacement effects. Most replacement effects use the word “instead” to indicate what events will be replaced with other events.

Comment: I know it doesn't use "instead", but Teysa Karlov's ability smells a lot like a replacement effect.

Comment: On Teysa it wouldn't make a difference either way, since the death event wouldn't be replaced, only the trigger event. If anything, Nightmare Shepherd's ability might make things interesting if it was a replacement effect.

Comment: Note that the "if you do" part is essential here. It says that you only get a token if you exile the card, which is something you can only do once. If it had been left out (as well as the "may", presumably) you would get two tokens.